# How do I correctly use %p and %f in postgresql.conf to make the Write Ahead Log?

Tags: postgresql, write-ahead-logging

I am attempting to modify postgresql.conf (Postgre SQL 10.0 under Ubuntu 18.04 VPS) to setup the Write Ahead Log (WAL).

AIUI, the commands should be:

```
wal_level = replica             # minimal, replica, or logical
archive_mode = on               # enables archiving; off, on, or always
                                # (change requires restart)
archive_command = 'cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/pg_wal/%f'          
archive_timeout = 600           # force a logfile segment switch after this
                                # number of seconds; 0 disables
```

AIUI, %p references the database file (to be archived) and %f references the filename that will contain the copy of said database file.

In this case: I am saying to copy every 5 minutes the database file to the /pg_wal directory.

However, this is clearly not correct as the error log files shows:

```
cp: 'pg_wal/000000010000000000000002' and '/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/pg_wal/000000010000000000000002' are the same file
2020-02-16 21:01:05.857 UTC [20707] LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2020-02-16 21:01:05.857 UTC [20707] DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: cp pg_wal/000000010000000000000002 /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/pg_wal/000000010000000000000002
```

So I am not sure how %p and/or %f are supposed to be used. If someone could present the syntax, I would be most grateful.

Comment: That command is for _archiving_ the WAL files, not for "setting it up". And the archiving should be done to a different directory than the one where the file is created. Your archive_command tries to copy the file onto itself

Comment: I see. So the /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/pg_wal/ directory is where PostgreSQL actually creates the database then?

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the WAL segment *somewhere else*, not to its original location.

“Somewhere else” in this context means different storage on a different physical machine. So `cp` is only a good method of archival if the destination is an NFS mount or similar. Otherwise, `scp` would be better.

You have to make as sure as you can that any trouble that befalls the original database won't affect the WAL archives.

It is also a good idea to test if the `cp` would overwrite anything, like the example in the documentation does. Otherwise, if two clusters archive to the same directory by mistake, you could end up with data loss.